# ZipFile Class not recognised by visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

I am trying to use ZipFile.OpenRead() but the thing is no matter how much i try it is not working in the program, whatever nugetpackage or code i use.

I tried System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead() this did not work, instead I was asked to use ZipArchive by visual studio.

I imported both System.IO.Compression.ZipFile and System.IO.Compression nuget packages but still there is no change, what more can i do?

The code is here: [Link](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/blob/32a22e75c7f1d4b5f114856622c7364367cf870c/tools/metadata_tools/templates/solutions/iOS/Infrastructure/DataManager.cs), Line no. 167.

Comment: Be sure to read the [note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` in your project to get `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`.